# Swift: Removing duplicate objects from array with a UUID

Tags: arrays, swift, uuid, diffabledatasource

I am using a UUID to get the use of DiffableDataSource but I am working with a data set that has a duplicate of every object.

Here is a sample of the code I am working with from a playground:

```
var movies: [MovieSearch] = []

struct MovieSearch: Hashable, Decodable, Equatable {
    let uuid = UUID()
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case Name, StartDate }
    
    let Name: String
    let StartDate: String
}
    
movies = [
  MovieSearch(Name: "Blade Runner", StartDate: "01/01/2021"), 
  MovieSearch(Name: "Blade Runner: 2049", StartDate: "01/07/2021"),     
  MovieSearch(Name: "UBIK", StartDate: "01/14/2021"),    
  MovieSearch(Name: "Blade Runner", StartDate: "01/01/2021"),    
  MovieSearch(Name: "Blade Runner: 2049", StartDate: "01/07/2021"),    
  MovieSearch(Name: "UBIK", StartDate: "01/14/2021")    
]
```

Since the UUID is added at the time of initialization is there a reasonable way to delete the duplicates in this scenario?

Comment: What are you use uuid for?

Comment: BTW Swift's convention is to use `lowerCamelCase` for all identifiers that aren't types, so `name`, `startDate`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm guessing what you want to do is to remove those duplicates?

Then write a function that removes the duplicates based on the name of the movie (which I'm guessing is unique) and use it to filter.

```
func removeDup(movies: [MovieSearch]) -> [MovieSearch] {
    var uniqueMovies = Set<String>()
    var moviesWithoutDups = [MovieSearch]()
    
    for movie in movies {
        if !uniqueMovies.contains(movie.name) {
            moviesWithoutDups.append(movie)
            uniqueMovies.insert(movie.name)
        }
    }
    return moviesWithoutDups
}
```

Then use the function:

```
movies = removeDup(movies: movies)
```

Comment: This is it exactly. Thank you!

Comment: @tylerperkins please mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `uniqued` method from Apple's [`swift-algorithms` package](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms).

You can see the method's source [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/195e0316d7ba71e134d0f6c677f64b4db6160c46/Sources/Algorithms/Unique.swift#L115).

It allows you to specify which fields in the object you want to compare for duplication. So in your scenario, you can use it as follows:

```swift
movies = movies.uniqued(on: \.Name)
print(movies)
```

*Note: you do need your struct to conform to `Hashable` to use this (which in this instance you already are conforming to it*)

For those that don't want to click the link for some reason. Here's the code provided by Apple:

```
@inlinable
func uniqued<Subject: Hashable>(
    on projection: (Element) throws -> Subject
) rethrows -> [Element] {
    var seen: Set<Subject> = []
    var result: [Element] = []
    for element in self {
        if seen.insert(try projection(element)).inserted {
            result.append(element)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

**Edit:**

Updated answer with key path in `uniqued` method. As suggested by [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3141234/alexander)

Comment: `movies.uniqued(on: \.Name)` would also work, and reads a touch nicer

Comment: Nice. I forgot about key paths for a second. I'll update the answer

Comment: You don't have to give edit explanations like that for such small tweaks. If people are interested, they can just see the edit history

Comment: Fair enough. I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the order of your Movies, you can use a Swift's Set.

Since your `MovieSearch` conforms to the Hashable protocol, Set will ensure that only exactly one copy exists.

You can iterate through the Set using `for-in` notation, similar to an array.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set

```
struct MovieSearch: Hashable, Decodable, Equatable {
    let uuid = UUID()
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case Name, StartDate }
    
    let Name: String
    let StartDate: String
}
    
var movies:Set = [
  MovieSearch(Name: "Blade Runner", StartDate: "01/01/2021"), 
  MovieSearch(Name: "Blade Runner: 2049", StartDate: "01/07/2021"),     
  MovieSearch(Name: "UBIK", StartDate: "01/14/2021"),    
  MovieSearch(Name: "Blade Runner", StartDate: "01/01/2021"),    
  MovieSearch(Name: "Blade Runner: 2049", StartDate: "01/07/2021"),    
  MovieSearch(Name: "UBIK", StartDate: "01/14/2021")    
]

for movie in movies {
   print(movie.Name)
}
```